# How to get a list of elements in Appium for all pages

Tags: c#, android, xpath, appium

I am using appium and .net drivers for android automation.
I was able to get the list of elements on single page using

IList Elements = Driver.FindElementsById("com.***xm.ivi.oem.**:id/item_title");

if I swipe the next page I have few more elements, My question how to get the list on the second page.

Comment: Any suggestions

Comment: Please help me out I am trying this from past 4 days

Comment: may be show your full code and explain "few more elements"  like show their structure using `uiautomatorviewer` or something else

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question... But if you want to get screen2 list of elements... You will have to do the same thing you pasted after screen2 was loaded.

```
IList Elements2 = Driver.FindElementsById("com.*xm.ivi.oem.:id/item_title");
```

Note that if the implementation is with a Recyclerview for example, you won't be able to locate elements that are not displayed at that moment.

Comment: Yaa I tried, I am using swipe method for the next screen, How could I know how many screens are left, Some scenarios in my app I have 3 screens, some scenarios I have 9 screens.

Comment: I have a similar scenario but scrolling vertically... What I do (a very specific method that works with my app) is to get the first EditText at the screen. Then I scroll and I get the first EditText again to check if is at the same one, if is at another position... (If is the same and at the same position I reached the bottom of the screen) Maybe you should try the same. It is not the perfect implementation and is not the fastest one, but it works for me no matter how long my list is.

Comment: If you paste an image of Appium Inspector maybe I could try to do a sketch so you could see it better

Comment: Thanks Barbudito, I am not able to paste Image due to reputations, Please find the below link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView/master/assets/preview_anim_drop.gif

Comment: I need to find the count of page indicator and page number

Comment: To help you I need a structure, something like this: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/images/appium/app-opened-in-appium-desktop-inspector.png